# How to recover from error during bulk insert in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I am creating a web application with MongoDB.
Now I am creating admin pages, which enable administrators to add or remove items on the website.
On the page, bulk import feature will be added, which makes it possible to import contents from local CSV files.
The problem is how to implement the feature.

The simplest approach is to convert uploaded CSV files into JSON and just insert them using `db.items.insert([{...}, {...}, ...])` statement.

If `null` is returned by `db.getLastError()`, the import is succeeded. There is no problem.

However, what should be done if an error occurred during the bulk insert?
Because there is no transaction, the inserted items cannot be rolled back.
Therefore, retrying the insert will result in duplicated documents.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As at MongoDB 2.4, you will only get the last exception if there is an error for any of the documents in a [bulk insert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/write-operations/#bulk-inserts).

#### Rolling back on failure

If you want to have a transactional approach for a bulk insert (i.e. all inserts must succeed, or rollback the batch) then you should include an identifying field like `batch_id` in the documents inserted. On any failure you can then remove any documents that were inserted from that batch and handle the error appropriately (retry or fail).

#### Bulk insert approaches

If you are **not** inserting into a sharded cluster:

- set the `ContinueOnError` flag to false to ensure that the bulk insert stops on the first error
- handle exceptions and decide whether to rollback the batch or re-insert starting from the document after the one that caused the exception

If you **are** inserting into a sharded cluster:

- the `ContinueOnError` flag is currently always set to true
- on error you will have to loop through the documents in that batch and try to insert (or [upsert](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/update/#update-operations-with-the-upsert-flag)) them individually so you can catch and handle any specific exceptions.
- see also: [Strategies for Bulk Inserts to a Sharded Collection](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/bulk-write-operations/index.html#strategies-for-bulk-inserts-to-a-sharded-collection).

Comment: You may also wish to upvote/watch [SERVER-9038](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-9038) in the MongoDB Jira issue tracker.  This feature suggestion includes enhancements to bulk inserts that would allow you to specify `ContinueOnError` as `true` and see which writes failed (rather than only including the last error for the batch).

Comment: `ContinueOnError` seems to be deprecated. How are errors in bulkOps handled now? Does the bulkop stop completely or does it continue with other operations?