# Getting unauthorized error during bulk insertions

Tags: mongodb, azure

I am dumping some collections and trying to restore them to cosmosDb

Dumping method

```
mongodump --host localhost:5960 --db test --collection ‘collectionName’ --gzip --out /mongoBackupFolder/
```

Restoring method

```
 mongorestore --host blahblah.azure.com --port 9999 -u user -p password --db dummyData --collection dummyData /mongoBackupDB/dummyData/dummyData.bson.gz --gzip --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates
```

In some collections I have milions of data and sometimes during insertion time i am getting

```
Error 13 : Insert Error
```

Error 13 is `13 Unauthorized    The request lacks the permissions to complete.  Ensure you are using the correct keys.`

The error in azure portal

```
  The portal is having issues getting an authentication token. The experience rendered may be degraded.
```

Comment: You can refer to [MongoDB - Command failed with error code 13 not authorized by ***** to execute this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34864603/mongodb-command-failed-with-error-code-13-not-authorized-by-to-execute), [Azure MongoDB API Bulk Insert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43835779/azure-mongodb-api-bulk-insert) and [How to recover from error during bulk insert in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16210863/how-to-recover-from-error-during-bulk-insert-in-mongodb)

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem. I want to migrate data from MongoDB to CosmosDB, I have a large collection (33+ million documents) that consistently fails to restore at the same point (53%) with a bunch of "Error 13". 
Suggestions from @Ecstasy don't apply:
- It's not an actual permission error as it happens in the middle of the restore
- I want to use mongorestore, not do a bulk insert.
Did you come up with a solution?